# Best way to generate feeds from pages that doesn't have RSS support

Tags: php, rss, feed

The best example I saw so far is the http://www.instapaper.com/ . They can get the text from any page.

In my case, I need to get the text and also generate a list considering that I will have one page with the news list of each site.

For example, nytimes.com (just an example). I have to get all links and get the text if it exists. Also, maybe I need to specify some URL criteria, like generate feeds from links where the url contains something like "/[year]/[month/[day]/[category]/post-name".

I don't want the complete code, just the concept and best approach. Any ideias?

Comment: How about [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is painful but the only good solution is to use an HTML parser and parse all the hrefs. I recommend using a library that allows you to easily select all hrefs. I have heard of this one http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ but never used it. What you would do is load each page and then select all hrefs.

There is really no easier way. If you changed your technology to something like java or python, then you can leverage multi-thread power and speed up the process. Of course once you analyze, save the data in some database so you can later reference it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to get only the post text from a specific page, like instapaper?

Comment: Are familiar with jquery? this php lib mirror the functions in jqeury. You can do something like $py->text() to get only the text and no html mark up.

Comment: But I have to find the text first, no? I mean, first I have to know the specific location of the text and then get it. And jquery is not the the best option because it's on the client side and in this case I'm in the server side, the DOM inspection will be done with php. I need to know the best way to get only the post text, since the page will contain a lot of other unrelated things.

Comment: Sorry! Actually you post phpquery not jquery =P. So, the problem is only get the specific text.

Comment: No, I am saying phpquery is similar to jquery. So if you know jquery then you should be able to use phpquery easily. Sorry if i was not clear.